# How do you prevent PHPStorm from opening a project on start?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

It takes a while to open some larger projects and I am just wondering if I get to the "Welcome to PHPStorm" screen by default instead of the last opened project.

Comment: The only way I know how is by closing a project before closing PHPStorm.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Appearance & Behavior | System Settings`
3. `Reopen last project on startup`

[image]

**P.S.**
Settings screen has very handy search box (top left corner) which will narrow possible options **a lot**.

---

**UPDATE 2020-12-02:** Current 2020.2 version has a bit different name to clarify that it will reopen ALL previously opened projects and not just only last one.

[image]

Comment: Excellent suggestion for the search.  I kept struggling with the correct term for this.

Comment: In newer versions of PhpStorm this setting can be found under Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Reopen last project on statup.

Answer (score 4):

On **UBUNTU OS** In PHP-Storm 8.0.3, It was as

1. File
2. Settings
3. Appearance & Behavior
4. System Settings
5. Reopen last project on startup ( *uncheck this checkbox* )

Answer (score 4):

If you try to check uncheck Reopen last project from the Settings | General Preferences on startup but are not able to reach the General Settings box (perhaps because PHPStorm is hanging when it tries to reopen the last project) you can do the following (instructions for Mac but similar for other OS):

```
vim ~/Library/Preferences/WebIde90/options/ide.general.xml
```

Add/edit the following to the `<application>` tag:

```
<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
```

This should allow you to restart without any problem.  In my case, I was not able to even finish starting PHPStorm until I made the change.  After I modified the file I restarted and went to File --> Invalidate Caches Restart as well.

For other OS you can view [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) page to help file the location of the file.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't help. On startup, it still opens last project, and settings show the option as checked (true).

Comment: worked when inside the "GeneralSettings" component. Edited

Comment: Newer versions of PHPStorm have this in `~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm*/options/recentProjectDirectories.xml` and under `<option name="openPaths"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Go here:

Settings > General

and uncheck "Reopen last project on startup"

Answer (score 2):

On Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

```
vi .PhpStorm2016.2/config/options/ide.general.xml
```

Adding `<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />` does the trick

```
<application>
  <component name="GeneralSettings">
    <option name="confirmExit" value="false" />
    <option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
  </component>
  <component name="Registry">
    <entry key="dumb.aware.run.configurations" value="true" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case people can't find it: It has been changed in newer versions of PHPStorm. 
It can now be found at Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC, open Command line and run below command

```
open -e Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2017.2/options/ide.general.xml
```

The ide.general.xml file should be fire up in TextEditor

Add the below under "showTipsOnStartup"

```
<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
```

So the file should now look like the below

```
<application>
  <component name="GeneralSettings">
    <option name="showTipsOnStartup" value="false" />
    <option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
  </component>
  <component name="Registry">
    <entry key="dumb.aware.run.configurations" value="true" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Then Save and Restart PHPSTORM. Yup. That's all

NOTE: Replace "PhpStorm2017.2" with your current PHPStorm name/version.

For Windows or Linux, locate the file and follow the same process.